# How to link VirtueMart v2.0 with K2?

Tags: joomla, virtuemart, joomla-k2

How to bridge the latest version of vituemart v2.0 with the K2 Jhoomla??

Comment: ich think, the easiest way is here, if you are still searchig for solution:
http://www.joomlaworks.net/content/view/86/42/

Answer (score 0):

According to [this post](http://forum.joomlaworks.gr/k2mart/k2mart-for-virtuemart-2-0/) :

> Virtuemart is a release candidate but the truth is that this is not
>   what it sounds like. Even in that stage they keep changing the
>   database scheme once a while so it is a little bit difficult to follow
>   this. We do plan to support Virtuemart 2 and Joomla! 1.7 but currently
>   there is no estimated date.

So I think you should wait and check [Joomlaworks](http://joomlaworks.gr) website for updates

Comment: But the thing is my client requirement is to use virtuemart2 and wants to use k2 as they are used to it, so what could be the best way to deliver the product now?

Comment: Right now I don't think there's a way out this but to explain to your client that VM2 is not final yet and there're extensive updates going to the RC now and changes to the database scheme. He should understand that waiting for the FINAL version of VM2 is the best decision otherwise you could invest time working on making the bridge between them both but you will lose the ability to upgrade to the future versions of VM or K2. It's a hard situation but It's the safest and most convenient.